# put element at the end of a TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, treemap

i have a Tree Map in which i have sorted elements  in ascending order like 0,1,2,3 etc.These elements are sorted on their values i.e 0,1,2 etc are values.I have used a comparator to sort them..I want to retain this order except that i want to put element with 0 value at the end of map.How to do it?

Comment: It sounds like what ever you are trying to do should be done a better way. For example, `0` can only appear once so it cannot appear at the start and the end.  Perhaps you could clarify what you need to do and we can come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: I am using a comparator to sort something and there are 0's also.But i want 0's at the end .Thats what i want..@Peter Lawrey

Comment: Instead of using `0` why not use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: i am not setting these values .All these values come from Shopping engine in a xml and i parse them using a digester. I have to sort the values now and the values which are null(0 is treated here as null only) are to be set at the last...I hope i didnt miss anything

Comment: If you really have no control over the values, the simplest solution will be to do what you suggest.  Using `0` as a null value is a bad idea, but it appears you have no choice.

Comment: Yup...i really dont have a choice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already said, your TreeMap is sorted, so it would be completely senseless to allow you to append an element at the "end", even though TreeMaps just don't work that way.

What you could do is configure your Comparator in a way that it decides that "0" is the largest element, so he will sort all "0" to the very end.
Please note that the order of "0"'s at the end is then random, depending on the sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your Comparator and treat 0 as the largest number

Answer (score 1):

Just realized, that you want to sort on map *values* rather then *keys*. The comparator does not get values which makes it a bit more complicated. The *new* approach uses a second (unsorted) map that just collects all values and can be used by the comparator to lookup the values for the keys:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> helper = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static Comparator<String> myComparator 
                  = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    Integer i1 = helper.get(s1);
    Integer i2 = helper.get(s2);

    if (i1 == 0) return  1; //  i1 > i2
    if (i2 == 0) return -1; //  i1 < i2

    return i1.compareTo(i2);
  } 
};

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  helper.put("minus one", -1);
  helper.put("zero", 0);
  helper.put("one", 1);
  helper.put("very much", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  helper.put("nothing", 0);
  helper.put("null", 0);

  Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(myComparator);
  map.putAll(helper);

  for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
minus one = -1
one = 1
very much = 2147483647
nothing = 0
zero = 0
null = 0
```

Comment: Can you help me out? I am not able to get them the above way

Comment: what if i have multiple 0's ? I won't be able to use "return i1.comapreTo(i2)" as it does not allow me duplicates. I am using if (val1 < val2  ) {
            return -1;
        } else if (val1 == val2) {
            return 0;
        } else  {
            return 1;
        }

Comment: and i am sorting not on their keys but on their "Values"

Comment: A Map does not allow duplicate keys. That's a feature. If you `put` another `0` as a key, then the new value will replace the existing one. That's how maps (and sets) work. We can't change maps to accept duplicate keys.

Comment: If I use it your way i wont be able to allow duplicates

Comment: Ah - wait - you want to collect all map entries with *value* 0 at the end of the map?? not the entry where the key equals 0, everything like `put(key, 0)`?